# How to prevent CSRF attack in asp.net webform?

Tags: webforms

How to prevent **CSRF** (*Cross-site Request Forgery*) attack in ASP.NET WebForms?

Is there anything like `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` in ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: This might be of interest to you: [How Do I: Prevent a Cross Site Request Forgery Security Flaw in an ASP.NET Application?][1]. [1]:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bb977433.aspx

Answer (score 0):

When you are talking about protecting the ViewState, there is the 'ViewStateUserKey', which you can use.

Basically you need to use a specific key per user, that is derived from the ASP.NET Session. Here's an example:

```
/// <summary>
///     Raises the <see cref="E:System.Web.UI.Control.Init" /> event to initialize the page.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="e">
///     An <see cref="T:System.EventArgs" /> that contains the event data.
/// </param>
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e) {
    base.OnInit(e);

    // Validate whether ViewState contains the MAC fingerprint
    // Without a fingerprint, it's impossible to prevent CSRF.
    if (!Page.EnableViewStateMac) {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("The page does NOT have the MAC enabled and the view state is therefore vulnerable to tampering.");
    }

    ViewStateUserKey = Session.SessionID;
}
```

You can learn more e.g. [from the Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.viewstateuserkey?view=netframework-4.8).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer as far as `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` is concerned probably is

```
if (IsPostBack)
    AntiForgery.Validate();
```

which throws an exception if no token is present.

The token can be added in a web form like this:

```
<%= System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.GetHtml() %>
```

Note that the namespace is `System.Web.Helpers` in the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages` Nuget-Package.

Here are some related threads:
[CSRF synchronize token pattern implementation in ASP.net webform app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45797825/csrf-synchronize-token-pattern-implementation-in-asp-net-webform-app)
and [preventing cross-site request forgery (csrf) attacks in asp.net web forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29939566/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-attacks-in-asp-net-web-forms)

For more information on the subject in general it might be helpful to search using the *Synchronizer Token Pattern (STP)* term.