# asp.net webforms how to validate CSRF Token

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, csrf-protection

How to validate **CSRF** Token with ajax request,i have added some code in **site.master** page.

```
        private const string AntiXsrfTokenKey = "__AntiXsrfToken";
        private const string AntiXsrfUserNameKey = "__AntiXsrfUserName";
        private string _antiXsrfTokenValue;

        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Contains("HtmlRender.aspx"))
            {
                //First, check for the existence of the Anti-XSS cookie
                var requestCookie = Request.Cookies[AntiXsrfTokenKey];
                Int32 requestCookieGuidValue;

                //If the CSRF cookie is found, parse the token from the cookie.
                //Then, set the global page variable and view state user
                //key. The global variable will be used to validate that it matches 
                //in the view state form field in the Page.PreLoad method.
                if (requestCookie != null
                    && Int32.TryParse(requestCookie.Value, out requestCookieGuidValue))
                {
                    //Set the global token variable so the cookie value can be
                    //validated against the value in the view state form field in
                    //the Page.PreLoad method.
                    _antiXsrfTokenValue = requestCookie.Value;

                    //Set the view state user key, which will be validated by the
                    //framework during each request
                    Page.ViewStateUserKey = _antiXsrfTokenValue;
                }
                //If the CSRF cookie is not found, then this is a new session.
                else
                {
                    //Generate a new Anti-XSRF token
                    _antiXsrfTokenValue = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");

                    //Set the view state user key, which will be validated by the
                    //framework during each request
                    Page.ViewStateUserKey = _antiXsrfTokenValue;

                    //Create the non-persistent CSRF cookie
                    var responseCookie = new HttpCookie(AntiXsrfTokenKey)
                    {
                        //Set the HttpOnly property to prevent the cookie from
                        //being accessed by client side script
                        HttpOnly = true,

                        //Add the Anti-XSRF token to the cookie value
                        Value = _antiXsrfTokenValue
                    };

                    //If we are using SSL, the cookie should be set to secure to
                    //prevent it from being sent over HTTP connections
                    if (FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL &&
                        Request.IsSecureConnection)
                    {
                        responseCookie.Secure = true;
                    }

                    //Add the CSRF cookie to the response
                    Response.Cookies.Set(responseCookie);
                }

                Page.PreLoad += master_Page_PreLoad;
            }
        }

        protected void master_Page_PreLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //During the initial page load, add the Anti-XSRF token and user
            //name to the ViewState
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                //Set Anti-XSRF token
                ViewState[AntiXsrfTokenKey] = Page.ViewStateUserKey;

                //If a user name is assigned, set the user name
                ViewState[AntiXsrfUserNameKey] =
                       Context.User.Identity.Name ?? String.Empty;
            }
            //During all subsequent post backs to the page, the token value from
            //the cookie should be validated against the token in the view state
            //form field. Additionally user name should be compared to the
            //authenticated users name
            else
            {
                //Validate the Anti-XSRF token
                if ((string)ViewState[AntiXsrfTokenKey] != _antiXsrfTokenValue
                    || (string)ViewState[AntiXsrfUserNameKey] !=
                         (Context.User.Identity.Name ?? String.Empty))
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Validation of " +
                                        "Anti-XSRF token failed.");
                }
            }
        }
```

When i click save button `save.aspx` which is not using master page,how can i validate with ajax request? 
below is set in cookies

```
Cookie:ASP.NET_SessionId=luzxp1452vhz133aqzp4apyg; __AntiXsrfToken=9df60e2882254df58e24093b65a4fccb
```

below is my ajax javascript

```
function save_data(AJAX, save_fun) {


    var sPath = window.location.pathname;
    sPath = sPath.substring(sPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    AJAX.addData('PageName', sPath);

    AJAX.action = 'C'; ///Custom
    AJAX.showProgress(true);
    AJAX.addHeaderAction(AJAX.action);

    AJAX.createXMLreq();
    AJAX.xmlhttp = AJAX.getAjaxObject();
    AJAX.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

        if (AJAX.xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && AJAX.xmlhttp.status == 200) {

            AJAX.resXML = AJAX.xmlhttp; 


        } else {
            AJAX.showProgress(true);
        }
    }
    AJAX.xmlhttp.open("POST", "save.aspx", true);
    AJAX.xmlhttp.send(AJAX.reqXML);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I find it much easier to use System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery namespace.  Seems to do all the work.

Look at the 2nd answer here: [preventing cross-site request forgery (csrf) attacks in asp.net web forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29939566/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-attacks-in-asp-net-web-forms)