# Antiforgery.Validate() does not seem to work? CSRF issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, csrf, x-xsrf-token

I have placed the code below inside my forms. The request would then show a token in its cookie, and also a hidden field is created when my html is being generated. Note that both the cookie and the hidden field have different values.

```
<%= System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.GetHtml() %>
```

Everytime i postback, i have the validator shown below.

```
if (IsPostBack)
{
   AntiForgery.Validate();
}
```

1. The weird part is that even if I change the cookie in the hidden field forcefully (using MITM software like burp). the validator would not even detect that the token has been changed.
2. I have listed down the generated tokens (refreshing the page a couple of times) and tried using one of the listed ones to manipulate the most current request. And to no surprise, the validator does not catch an error.
3. I read that the tokens are session based so I tried to use the token on another session (another user). and still, the validator does not catch anything.
4. Changing the token in the cookie would catch an error, but that cookie token is constant and is the same for all forms.

Is there anything wrong or any other missing pieces to this issue?

Comment: What version of MVC are you using?

Comment: Im using asp.net webforms

Comment: What version of ASP.NET Web Forms? What version of VS?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry. Asp version is 4.0 and vs is 2015.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29939566/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-attacks-in-asp-net-web-forms

Comment: Perhaps you could use one of the Validate overloads such as `   AntiForgery.Validate(cookieValue, httpContext.Request.Headers["__RequestVerificationToken"]);
` to pass in your cookie and check against the request headers? See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.antiforgery(v=vs.111).aspx.

Comment: @irishChieftain i have already read that but there is no master page generate in my solution.

Comment: @matt, thanks ill try this one out.

Comment: @kberStill how did you go?

Comment: @matt, it didnt do anything. I dont know what went wrong. Or what I missed

Comment: I think its because the cookie token remains constant as long as I use the same browser. The form token is constantly changing.

Comment: Is there a way to regenerate the cookieToken?

Answer (score 0):

Well, It's advised on the [OWASP Cheatsheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Anti_CSRF_Tokens_ASP.NET) to use/check the ViewStateUserKey and to double submit the cookie value. You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29962060/7827699).

Although this will only protect the requests coming from the Web Forms. In other cases like sending an AJAX POST to the server won't have the token. So you may in this case implement a custom header with the an auto-generated token and check it on the server side.
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/23371/csrf-protection-with-custom-headers-and-without-validating-token