# How prevent cross-site request forgery (csrf) attacks in asp.net web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, csrf

In my ASP web application, while I'm doing the pen test using OWASP, it shows

> form does not contain an anti-csrf token

So I read several articles to avoid this issue. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36152716/3703534) solution from Stackoverflow.
As he saying I need to add this code  `<%= System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.GetHtml() %>` inside the web form.But My `.aspx` code as follows.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Common/OLTMaster.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="MyAccount.aspx.cs" Inherits="LTSWeb.Admin.MyAccount" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/common.js"></script>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">

        <ContentTemplate>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" valign="top">
                        <div class="MyAccount">
                            <div class="sectionContentWrapUp">
                                <table style="width: 100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                                            <table style="width: 100%;" class="gridOutLine striped-table">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td align="right" width="50%">User Name:&nbsp;
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td align="left" width="50%">
                                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" CssClass="txtbox" Width="120px"
                                                            MaxLength="30" TabIndex="1"></asp:TextBox>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td align="right" width="50%">Password:&nbsp;
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td align="left" width="50%">
                                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rvPassword" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPassword"
                                                            CssClass="errorMsg" ErrorMessage="Invalid password" ValidationGroup="vgUser">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>                                               
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="left">
                                            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnSaveUser" runat="server" CssClass="buttonHover" OnClick="btnSaveUser_Click"
                                                SkinID="btnSave" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

And this is how my `aspx.cs`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            //Some code here
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.LogErrorEvent(ex);
    }
}

protected void btnSaveUser_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
   // user data save code goes here
}
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36152716/3703534) answer. How I need to change my code. please help me. And I found another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29939566/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-attacks-in-asp-net-web-forms/29962060#29962060) to prevent CSRF attack. But in my Master page does no contain `Page_Init` function. Do I need to add it manually?