# CSRF synchronize token pattern implementation in ASP.net webform app

Tags: asp.net, webforms, csrf

CSRF synchronize token pattern implementation in ASP.net webform app, I have added this `<%= System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.GetHtml() %>` in aspx page and

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (IsPostBack)
     AntiForgery.Validate();
  }
```

and it working perfect fine.

Now, I have requirement of implementing similar changes on 100+ pages and across multiple apps. In the current framework I have Base class for each page\view where i added  `AntiForgery.Validate();` in overridden method `Page_Load()`, but how can i add this  `<%= System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.GetHtml() %>` code in aspx page through C# code dynamically?

Basically, how to add `<%= System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.GetHtml() %>` to all asp.net web forms dynamically with C# code?

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace WebAppForXSRF
{
    public partial class SiteMaster : MasterPage
    {        
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                AntiForgery.Validate();
            }
        }

    protected  override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        LiteralControl literalContols = new LiteralControl();
        literalContols.Text = System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.GetHtml().ToHtmlString();
        this.MasterForm.Controls.Add(literalContols);
    }
```

}